# How to send logs into elastic - logstash

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I need to send logs into elastic and then watch them with kibana
I've done this

1.this is my yml file

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: ELK-STACK-EXAMPLE

server:
  port: 9898

logging:
  file: /pedro/IdeaProjects/elk-stack-logging-example/src/main/resources/elk-stack.log
```

this is .conf file

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "/pedro/IdeaProjects/elk-stack-logging-example/src/main/resources/elk-stack.logIdeaProjects/elk-stack-logging-example/src/main/resources/elk-stack.log"
    start_position =>"beginning"
  }
}

output {
  stdout{
      codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["***********************************************************"]
  }
}
```

in hosts it's written the host:port

in "kibana" I want to create index pattern with logstash-* ,but it says not match with indexes

do I need to create index ?

I even added'

```
hosts => ['host']

user => 'elastic'
password => '******'

index => don't know what to type
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write into the index.

For example: index => "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

In this case the Logstash will write into day rollower index "logstash-TODAY_DATE